# Converting from Oracle to Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I'm having trouble converting this to MySql. I originally had this in an Oracle Database, but I'm getting an error on line 6. How can I fix this?

```
create table racewinners (
    racename varchar(20) not null,
    raceyear integer,
    ridername varchar(20) not null,
    distance integer,
    winning_time INTERVAL DAY (9) TO SECOND (2), 
    constraint racewinners_rname_ryear_pk primary key (racename, raceyear),
    constraint racewinners_raceriders_fk foreign key (ridername) references raceriders(ridername)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have an `interval` data type.  You should be able to use `datetime` for this.  The following is a typical way to write this for MySQL:

```
create table racewinners (
    racename varchar(20) not null,
    raceyear integer,
    ridername varchar(20) not null,
    distance int,
    winning_time datetime, 
    primary key (racename, raceyear),
    foreign key (ridername) references raceriders(ridername)
);
```